# Applying filter then modify different column through Macro

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Referring on the below table, under **Column "F"** there's a filter with the following options:
**Laboratory, Dental, Optical**

Now, what I need is to filter for example Laboratory under Column "F" then autofill all in the Column "D" with Outpatient.
Next is filter again Dental under Column "F" then autofill all in the Column "D" with Dental. Then the same process for the filter Optical.

[image: Capture]

I tried to record Macro and below was the result:

```
Sub test()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$2252").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Dental"
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dental"
    Selection.FillDown
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$2252").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Optical"
    Range("D42").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Optical"
    Range("D42").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$2252").AutoFilter Field:=6

End Sub
```

However, I cannot use this record as some of my sheets have different value for example in cell "D3" is sometimes Optical unlike in the above example.

Thank you in advance for helping me on this.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding the question, but wouldn't it be simpler to use a vertical lookup to a small table somewhere else?

Comment: I agree with SAM. That is simpler and faster. But if you really want to, use `SpecialCells` property `xlCellTypeVisible` and iterate though it and input the text you want. However, `AutoFill` correctly fills the cells if 2 or more filters are active. Also, I think in 2013 XL, you can use `AutoFill` even if one column is filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through an array of values and feed the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) criteris one at a time. As mentioned, the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with a [xlCellType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) or **xlCellTypeVisible** will be sufficient to isolate the filtered rows.

```
Sub meddenlab()
    Dim a as long, arr As Variant

    arr = Array("Laboratory", "Dental", "Optical")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=arr(a)
                'step down one row off the header
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    'first check to see if there are visible cells
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        'there are visible rows - apply the ben typ
                        .Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = arr(a)
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter
            Next a
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

If the benefit type in column D did not match the benefit type in column F, two arrays of equal size could be used. Use the first as criteria on column F and the second as the value for column D.

Comment: Okay I got the logic! Thank you so much. I learn a lot from all your answers.